# Capybara doesn't care about event.preventDefault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

Testing Ruby on Rails application with RSpec, Capybara and Selenium.

I want to click an anchor which has an `href` but shouldn't lead anywhere due to the `event.preventDefault`. Nonetheless the link leads the test to the linked page instead of remaining on the current one.

**My first impression is that Javascript isn't working**. Besides for other tests I can see Firefox doing some stuff, but I can say the same thing for this specific test. Is there anything I'm missing?

If I test the page on the dummy app `event.preventDefault` works as intended.

Current test is:

```
describe "In field group editor, user", type: :feature do

    let(:user) { User.first }

    before(:context) do
        @structure = create(:structure)
    end

    it "should be able to create a checkbox" do
        sign_in user

        # should be login page
        save_and_open_page # and it is

        path_to_structure = edit_structure_path( structure_id: @structure.slug )
        visit path_to_structure

        find "#add-new-setting"

        # should be structure page
        save_and_open_page # and it is

        click_on "add-new-setting" # this should fire an ajax call and preventDefault link behaviour

        # should be still structure page
        save_and_open_page # instead capybara it's gone to the new setting page

        # ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to add `js: true` in the initial description.

BTW I'm not deleting the question as someone else might lose time looking for solving a similar issue and not realising the solution was that simple!